# How to get notification when a program is blocked from making Outbound connections in Windows by Firewall?

Tags: windows-10, networking, internet, firewall, notifications

in Firewall settings of Windows 10, there is only an option to show notification when a program is blocked from receiving inbound connections; how can i achieve the opposite result? to receive notification when a program or service is blocked from making Outbound connections? (preferably only if not explicitly blocked by a firewall rule).

thanks in advance.

[image]